# checking the system idleness and put the system into logout state after 5 minutes( if no one using)

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, timer, system-idle-process

Is there anything that provides system idleness ? We want to use C# to get the idle time for the system across all sessions and put the machine to logout  if nobody is using the machine for X minutes.

any idea about this .....

Comment: Are you wanting to auto-logout a session on a windows terminal server or like a desktop session? I have a solution for both, but how to do it depends if you are running a terminal server.

Comment: yaa .. I have windows(DESKTOP APPS) form with login button and some sessions are running  when user login and i want do auto logout when user not using any forms when he login the system...    would you pls post two solutions for me.. that would really help me ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running a terminal server this can be done through group polices or through terminal services configuration

[Server 2003](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758177%28WS.10%29.aspx)

[Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754272%28WS.10%29.aspx)

[Server 2008 R2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754272.aspx)

---

To log off a desktop session you will need to have a program that runs in the background (this will not work as a system service, it must be running as part of the interactive session) that will check the login time with `GetLastInputInfo`, it then can call `ExitWindowsEx`to log off.

```
class Program
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct LASTINPUTINFO
    {
        public static readonly int SizeOf = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LASTINPUTINFO));

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int cbSize;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public UInt32 dwTime;
    }


    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool ExitWindowsEx(uint uFlags, uint dwReason);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool running = true;
        while (running)
        {
            if (GetLastInputTime() > 60 * 15) //15 min idle time
            {
                ExitWindowsEx(0, 0);
                running = false;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60); //check once per min.
        }
    }

    static int GetLastInputTime()
    {
        int idleTime = 0;
        LASTINPUTINFO lastInputInfo = new LASTINPUTINFO();
        lastInputInfo.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(lastInputInfo);
        lastInputInfo.dwTime = 0;

        int envTicks = Environment.TickCount;

        if (GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInputInfo))
        {
            int lastInputTick = (int)lastInputInfo.dwTime;

            idleTime = envTicks - lastInputTick;
        }

        return ((idleTime > 0) ? (idleTime / 1000) : 0);
    }

}
```

I needed to do this once and had trouble finding sources and this may help someone else who is goggleing this kind of question. So even though I am answering, I am down voting the question.

**UPDATE**: [Here is a technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494436/getting-user-idle-time-in-c/6494967#6494967) to get this to run as a service

Comment: is there any service like we add timer to windows form.. when user login the timer counts start and when the user does not do any thing then the timer is zero and the system is automatically logout .... i am looking for this type of service ... would you pls give any idea about this.....